# Google Maps API V3 IF else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I would like to ask your kind help about showing just the selected markers in Google Maps API V3.

I have a HTML select ->

```
<select onchange="appartments()" id="selectField">
<option value="appartment1">Choose one appartment...</option>
<option value="appartment2">1052 Budapest, Galamb u. 3.</option>
<option value="appartment3">1052 Budapest, Régi posta u. 11.</option>
<option value="appartment4">1052 Budapest, Régi posta u. 14.</option>
<option value="appartment5">1051 Budapest, Vörösmarty tér 2.</option>
<option value="appartment6">1066 Budapest, Ó u. 5.</option>
</select>
```

I have the API V3 and the markers ->

```
function appartments() {
    var get_id = document.getElementById('selectField');
    console.log(get_id);
    var result = get_id.options[get_id.selectedIndex].value;
    }

IF ELSE HERE!   
var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(47.5037832, 19.0575725));
marker.setMap(map);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(47.4947063,19.0527723));
marker.setMap(map);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(47.4968459,19.0505202));
marker.setMap(map);


var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(47.494265,19.0516276));
marker.setMap(map);


var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(47.4933959,19.0515483));
marker.setMap(map);

}
```

I would like to get the marker which is selected in HTML select, for example ->

```
if (result = appartment1) {

var marker...

} else if (result = appartment2) {

var marker..

} and so..
```

Could anybody help me giving me a simple way for solving this?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Tibor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a different approach can be used here instead of mapping all the objects and their `lat long` values. You are repeating yourself and an `if else` or `switch` is not making it easier. So I suggest, if your setup allows it, to add the `lat long` values as `data-` attribute to your options.

```
<select id="selectField">
    <option>Choose one appartment...</option>
    <option value="appartment1" data-lat="47.5037832" data-lng="19.0575725">1052 Budapest, Galamb u. 3.</option>
    <option value="appartment2" data-lat="47.4947063" data-lng="19.0527723">1052 Budapest, Régi posta u. 11.</option>
    <option value="appartment3" data-lat="47.4947063" data-lng="19.0527723">1052 Budapest, Régi posta u. 14.</option>
    <option value="appartment4" data-lat="47.4947063" data-lng="19.0527723">1051 Budapest, Vörösmarty tér 2.</option>
    <option value="appartment5" data-lat="47.4947063" data-lng="19.0527723">1066 Budapest, Ó u. 5.</option>
</select>
```

Also remove the `value` on the first options since it's only there to enhance usability and is not supposed to pass any value `onchange`. Also if you're assigning a function `appartments()` to the `onchange` attribute, it doesn't make sense to retrieve the element "again" with `document.getElementById('selectField')`. Either bind the function in JavaScript or pass `this` to `appartments()` like `onchange="appartments(this)"`.

On to the JavaScript part, about repeating yourself, you basically want to change the selectbox `selectField` and create a marker with the proper `lat long` data.

```
var selectField = document.getElementById('selectField');
selectField.onchange = function(){
    var data = this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset,
        marker = new google.maps.Marker();

    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data.lat), parseFloat(data.lng)));
    marker.setMap(map);
}
```

**UPDATE**

To change the marker `onchange` you only create one marker, and update it's position accordingly. This can be done with a delegate function. It runs onload, evaluating the variables and binds a new function instead, keeping the variables in memory.

```
selectField.onchange = (function(){
    var data, 
        marker = new google.maps.Marker();        

    return function(){
        data = selectField.options[selectField.selectedIndex].dataset;
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data.lat), parseFloat(data.lng)));
        marker.setMap(gmap);
    };
}());
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/9X8QF/)**

Comment: Thank you very much it did the trick for me! One more question if i may ask, when I select another apartment, the previous marker won't disappear. Could you help me solving this also please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've updated the demo and the answer so you should be all set ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up the difference between `=` which is an *assignment operator*, `==` which is a loose *comparison operator* and `===` which is a *strict comparison operator*.

```
if (result === "appartment1") {

var marker...

} else if (result === "appartment2") {

var marker..

}
```

That said -- I'd actually recommend using a 'switch' statement here.

```
switch(result) {
case "appartment1":
  // do something
  break;
case "appartment2":
  // do something
  break;
}
```

Comment: Here is a good reference on JS comparison operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: @RobM. Thanks -- I should have included that link.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, why switch over if else?

Comment: I find the syntax of the `switch` statement to be much cleaner.  It also obvious, to the reader, that you are looking at a set of possible values for one variable.  If you are using `TypeScript` yo can even get some extra type protection to make sure you have all options covered.

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to add the locations to an object, and index them via the selection value.

```
<select id="selectField">
    <option value="appartment1">Choose one appartment...</option>
    <option value="appartment2">1052 Budapest, Galamb u. 3.</option>
    <option value="appartment3">1052 Budapest, Régi posta u. 11.</option>
    <option value="appartment4">1052 Budapest, Régi posta u. 14.</option>
    <option value="appartment5">1051 Budapest, Vörösmarty tér 2.</option>
    <option value="appartment6">1066 Budapest, Ó u. 5.</option>
</select>
```

---

```
var markers = {
    apartment1: [47.5037832, 19.0575725],
    apartment2: [47.4947063,19.0527723],
    apartment3: [47.4968459,19.0505202],
    apartment4: [47.494265,19.0516276],
    apartment5: [47.4933959,19.0515483],
    apartment6: [47.4947063,19.0527723]  
}

function apartmentUpdate() {
    var location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    if(markers[location]) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
        var coords = markers[location];
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]));
        marker.setMap(map);
    } else {
        console.error('No marker found for this apartment!');
    }        
}

document.getElementById('selectField')
    .addEventListener('change', apartmentUpdate, false);
```

Comment: It also might be best to include the name of the location in the object and populate the select element using the object's contents. I didn't include it in the example as it depends on your application, but it's something to think about. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am absolutely a newbie to JavaScript, I added your code instead of my code, this did not do the trick for me, or I am not good enough to understand your help properly. :( I am wondering about maybe the code is good, just Maps API can't refresh it automatically?

Comment: I read your code incorrectly, I imagined an array when there was not one. Updated my code.

EDIT: I do recommend Tim Vermaelen's answer if you have static positions though.

Comment: Same here! It solved my problem, so thanks for your kind help, but I want the not selected markers to disappear. Do you have any fast ideas for it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes! You'll simply have to track the markers and set their map to "null".

Comment: See Tim's implementation, he changes the position of a single map marker. This should be what you're looking for.